# Should I unit test multiple (different) input values to a function?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Give the following function:

```
public class UnderTest
{
   public bool Foo(Bar input)
   {
      if(input.State != State.Paid)
         throw new Exception();

      return true; 
   }
}
```

Whats the best way to test `input.State != State.Paid` given that `State` is an `enum`? I came up with the following. However, this will not catch if a new enum value is added. Is there a better way to test this or should I only care about a single test?

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(State.New)]
[InlineData(State.Cancelled)]
[InlineData(State.Complete)]
public void NotPaidBar_ThrowsException(State state)
{
    // Arrange
    var bar = new Bar()
    {
        State = state
    };

    var underTest = new UnderTest();

    // Act
    Action result = () => underTest.Foo(bar);

    // Assert
    result
        .ShouldThrow<Exception>();
}
```

Comment: You could create an `IState` interface with a `bool UnderTest()` method definition.  This way, all state implementations will have to implement `UnderTest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to consider that unit-tests will not ensure that your program is correct, but only that it isn't broken as per your definitions.

As for your particular question, if you're using TDD with triangulation, and if you stumble upon a new test that doesn't force you to write any new production code, then I would feel that the extra test is not useful from a productivity standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can test all the states with a simple loop if you want to, even those that would be added later to the enum:

```
public void NotPaidBar_ThrowsException()
{
    var allStates = Enum.GetValues(typeof (State)).Cast<State>();

    foreach (var state in allStates.Except(new[]{State.Paid}))
    {
        // Arrange
        var bar = new Bar()
        {
            State = state
        };

        var underTest = new UnderTest();

        // Act
        Action result = () => underTest.Foo(bar);

        // Assert
        result.ShouldThrow<Exception>();
    }
}
```